# Getting: cannot find symbol error

Tags: java, variables, symbols

At the bottom of the code I try to pass the inputs to a new class called, ISPCharge.BUT I keep getting the 'cannot find symbol' error. Why is this so? ( I am a beginner.)

I am trying to pass the packageCode and Hours variables. Using the readHours and readPackage variables are a requirement for this code. Any suggestions? This class is already in the same folder as the class it is supposed to be connected to.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ISPBilling {


      static char packageCode;

      static double hours;

      public static void main (String[] Args){


    Scanner keyboard  = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the package code (A, B, or C): ");
    packageCode = keyboard.next(".").charAt(0);

     readPackage(packageCode);

  System.out.println("Enter the number of hours used: ");
      hours = keyboard.nextDouble();
      readHours(hours);

      };

      public static double readHours(double hours){

       if(hours >= 0){

        return hours;

      }else 

           System.out.println("Your entry, " + hours + " is invalid.");
           System.out.println();

           return hours = 0;
       };    

    public static char readPackage(char packageCode){

     if (packageCode == 'a' || packageCode == 'A'){

        packageCode = 'A';

        return 'A';

    }else if (packageCode == 'b' || packageCode == 'B'){

        packageCode = 'B';

        return 'B';

      }else if(packageCode == 'c' || packageCode == 'C'){

        packageCode = 'C';

        return 'C';

      }else{  


         System.out.println("Your entry, " + packageCode + " is invalid.");
           System.out.println();


       packageCode = 'A';

       }


       return packageCode;

     };


    public double classcharge(){

    readPackage(packageCode);

    readHours(hours);

    ISPCharge ISPCharger = new ISPCharge(hours, packageCode); // THIS IS IT.

    return hours;

    };
```

}

```
/** put your documentation for this class here
```

See Style Guild for format
   */
   public class ISPCharge
    {
   // variables describing this charge.
   private char packageCode;
   private double hours;

// declare your constants here.  They should use the private
   // visibility modifier.

```
  /**************************************************** 
* The constructor sets the package and hours attributes.
* @param pkg The code for the package, A, B, or C
* @param hours The number of hours this month
*/
public double ISPCharge( double hours,char packageCode)
{

  return hours;

 }

/************************************************
* calc charge will decide which package to apply
* and will return the correct cost.
*
* @return The charges for this month.
*/
public double calcCost(){

if (packageCode == 'A' && hours < 10){

    return calcA();

}else if(packageCode == 'A' && hours > 10){

  return calcA() + (hours  - 20) * 2;

}else if(packageCode == 'B'&& hours  < 20){

  return calcB();

}else if(packageCode == 'B' && hours  > 20 ){

  return (hours  - 20) + calcB();

}else if (packageCode == 'C'){

  calcC();

}else 

 return 0;


 return hours;
};


/************************************************
* calcA calculates the charges for package A
*
* The rest is left for you to fill in....
*/
public double calcA(){

 return 9.95;

};
// put the calcA method here

/************************************************
* calcB calculates the charges for package B
*
* The rest is left for you to fill in....
*/
public double calcB(){

return  13.95;


};
// put the calcB method here


/************************************************
* calcC calculates the charges for package C
*
* The rest is left for you to fill in....
*/
public double calcC(){

return 19.95;

};


// put the calcC method here


/** calcTax calculates the tax on the passed charge
 *
 * The rest is left for you to fill in....
 */
 public double calcTax(){

 return calcCost() / 5;


 };
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It seems class ISPCharge is not in same package as mentioned class. Hence you need to import class as below. Hope this answers your problem.

```
import your.package.ISPCharge ;
```

And change constructor with following definition,

because `public double ISPCharge( double hours,char packageCode)` is valid method but not a constructor as constructor cannot have return value.

```
public  ISPCharge( double hours,char packageCode)
{

  .......

 }
```

Comment: It is in my file, just not in this example. They are together.

Comment: Are these 2 classes residing under same package. Please share code of other class too.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for ISPCharge should not have a return type, since its job is to set up the object, not to return a value. Remove the word `double` and set up your private variables instead of returning a value:

```
public ISPCharge( double hours,char packageCode)
{

    this.hours=hours;
    this.packageCode=packageCode;

}
```